# Firebase Rules - secure add/delete friend on a social app

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I am experimenting on a social app based on Firebase and I would like to secure the user deletion of a friend by using Firebase rules.

My database table to store friends is structured like this:

```
Friends
{ 
     user1 
   { 
     user2 {friend_username=user2}
     user3 {friend_username=user3}
   }
     user2 
   { 
     user1 {friend_username=user1}
     user3 {friend_username=user3}
   } 

}
```

Lets say user1 deletes user2 from his friend list, my current issue is how to properly sanction a deletion action because it would require a fan of two deletes: first the deletion of user2 from user1 friendlist and the deletion of user1 from user2 friendlist.

I tried the following but I get an error:

```
"FRIENDS" :{
  "$username":{ 
  //Users can read as long as they are authenticated and their auth.name matches the table key 
  ".read": "auth != null && auth.name === $username",
  //Delete should be allowed if the auth.name matches an entry in the table 'Friends' (first part of the deletion) and if the auth.name requesting the delete is included in the 'friend_username' value inside the user2 friends (second deletion) .  
    ".write": "auth != null && root.child('FRIENDS').hasChild(auth.name) && root.child('FRIENDS').child($username).child(auth.name).child('friend_username').val()=== auth.name"
```

Please note that I am using fan update to perform the deletions.

I can't wrap my head around a proper structured way to sanction this deletion...Any suggestions???

Thanks!

Comment: I suggest looking into using Cloud Functions for Firebase to set up a trigger that makes sure the database is consistent when the user performs a write.

Comment: @DougStevenson thanks, i will consider this option as well, but i would prefer to use a rule that can fit my case if possible! Also the fan method ensures consistency but my issue here is to ensure security (so that a certain user cannot mess with other entries in the friendlist.)

Comment: You can block write access to the fanned items so no one can mess with them and leave only write access to the place where you want to trigger on changes.

Comment: @DougStevenson , good point but that would apply only in the functions case correct?

Comment: Yes, I think Cloud Functions is the best way to get this done.